# Update parent from most recent child with Process Builder

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I have a master-detail relationship between two custom objects: Case__c [parent], Case_Followup__c [child]

The parent object has a **text** field representing the last known intention for the case [Last_Known_Intention__c]. Multiple follow-up communications related to the case will take place over time. The child object has a **picklist** field with a list of intentions: Leaving, Undecided, Staying, Not Applicable [Intention__c]

When a new Case_Followup__c record is created OR when any existing Case_Followup__c record is edited AND Intention__c is set to either Leaving, Undecided, or Staying, I need Case__c.Last_Known_Intention__c to update with the text value from Case_Followup__c.Intention__c for the Case_Followup__c record with the most recent CreatedDate.

I think this sort of thing is usually done with a trigger, but I saw in another post that this can be done using the Process Builder ([link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/trigger-to-update-parent-object-value-with-child-value)), which is what I would prefer. However, I have not been able to do it on my own or find documentation for it.

**In short, is it truly possible to use the Process Builder to isolate the picklist value on the most recently created child record and push that to the parent record, and if so how exactly?**

Comment: I'm currently dealing with this.  It seems crazy.  I wrote the process, on the "child" which has Lookup to the parent (Account).  I want to simply push the ID of the "child" to a custom (lookup) field on the Account.  But the list of fields it's offering to me to update are from the *child*.  I clearly state directly above that it's "this field on the Account" we are updating.   I'm at a loss, an hour wasted on what theoretically was a 90 second setup.  Ugh.