# On Update of an opportunity field should update account field!

Tags: opportunity, account

I'm looking for a APEX Trigger code few of my Opportunity fields are there in account (Picklist/Date/Text) i'm looking for a code where i can apply logic!

Example - Contract duration (Picklist) 1year, 2 years, 3 years, 5Years.

Update on Opportunity should update Account.

Need help on this!

Comment: @user2591 Welcome to SFSE. We are glad to see you here. For your question, Have you started writing something. We can help you if you are having any issues with what you have written. If not, this can be a very good starting point. [Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro). Also please check if you can implement it by a workflow. That will be much simpler [Cross Object Workflows](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm&language=en)

Comment: Process Builder can help with this as well w/o code. Just a thought.

Comment: Have you already wrote anything ? It's not clear why you're not able to do this, and what your real question to us is.

Answer (score 1):

```
Trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity(after update){

    Set<Id> accId=new Set<Id>();
    List<account> updateAcc=new List<Account>
    Map<Id,Opportunity> oppMap=new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){
        Opportunity oldOpp=Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id);
        if(opp.picklisField!=oldOpp.picklistField || opp.Text!=oldOpp.Text){
         accId.add(opp.AccountId);
         oppMap.put(opp.AccountId,opp);
        }
    }
    List<account> accList=[select id,picklistField from Account where id in:accId];
    if(accList.size()>0){
       for(Account acc:accList){
          Opportunty opp= oppMap.get(acc.id);
          acc.piclistField=opp.PicklistField;
          acc.Text=opp.Text;
          updateAcc.add(acc);
       }
    }
     if(updateAcc.size()>0){
       update updateAcc; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[See here if this example helps (Updating Parent field)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/trigger-to-update-parent-object-value-with-child-value)

Build your own logic for your Business requirement.
And talking about How to update Parent Object Fields value on Child Field updates - Following code and comments will help you out there ----

```
trigger UpdateAmount on Quote__c (after insert, after update) { //You want it on update too, right?
      Map<ID, Opportunity> parentOpps = new Map<ID, Opportunity>(); //Making it a map instead of list for easier lookup
      List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

      for (Quote__c childObj : Trigger.new {
        listIds.add(childObj.Opportunity);
      }

      //Populate the map. Also make sure you select the field you want to update, amount
      //The child relationship is more likely called Quotes__r (not Quote__r) but check
      //You only need to select the child quotes if you are going to do something for example checking whether the quote in the trigger is the latest
      parentOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT id, amount Name,(SELECT ID, Total_List_Price__c FROM Quotes__r) FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

      for (Quote__c quote: Trigger:new){
         Opportunity myParentOpp = parentOpps.get(quote.Opportunity__c);
         myParentOpp.Amount = quote.Total_List_Price__c;
      }

      update parentOpps.values();
    }
```