# Need to update parent record from child object

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, wrapper-class

I have `CS_Order__c`(parent) and `cs_Order_Line_Item__c` (child) objects.
I need to update `CS_Order__c`  field ,but its not updating the parent record.
CSOrderMap=

```
public class testUpdate {
    public static void UpdateParent(Map<Id, String> CSOrderMap) {
        Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();

        List<cs_Order_Line_Item__c> ordLineitem = [SELECT Id, Name,CS_Order__r.Fullfilment_Status__c FROM cs_Order_Line_Item__c WHERE CS_Order__c IN :CSOrderMap.keySet()];
        if(!ordLineitem.isEmpty()){
            for(cs_Order_Line_Item__c sc: ordLineitem){
                sc.CS_Order__r.Reason__c='Banned';
               sc.Billing_Status__c='Error';
            }

            update ordLineitem;
        }   
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

I dont want to create a new instance and a new query as well.

```
CS_Order__c csord=new CS_Order__c();
    csord.Reason__c='Banned';
    csord.id= csord.CS_Order__r.id;
    ordslist.add(acc);

update ordLineitem;
update ordslist;
```

but i dont want to create a new instance.
Please suggest.

Comment: Please Take a look at provided link, your code will look similar .
 [Link1](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/08/how-to-update-child-records-when-parent.html)  [Link2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/trigger-to-update-parent-object-value-with-child-value)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it isn't required to do the check for an empty list:

```
if(!ordLineitem.isEmpty()){ ... }
```

1. If the list if empty - `foreach` won't try to loop,
2. If you run DML on an empty list of records (`update ordLineitem;`) - it won't perform any database action.

Due to your question - `CS_Order__r` record on every `cs_Order_Line_Item__c` is an independent entity and when you run `update ordLineitem;` there is no impact on `CS_Order__r` related parent record.

As you mentioned in your question, you could create an instance of `CS_Order__c` record and accumulate a new list. And when you are ready with a business logic, you could create a generic list to update all record in one DML operation:

```
// ordLineitems - list of cs_Order_Line_Item__c
// ordslist - list of CS_Order__c
List<SObject> recordsToUpdate = new List<SObject>(ordLineitems);
recordsToUpdate.addAll(ordslist);
update recordsToUpdate;
```

Comment: is this possible without creating an instance of order.

Comment: @aditi basically, when you refer to an order as `sc.CS_Order__r` in the loop, you get an instance of order. So you could use this instance to add to orders list and then update it as I mention above.